# Time complexity for searching a list of lists?

Tags: list, matrix, time-complexity

Suppose I store a matrix as a list of lists, where the first list represents the rows, and each element in that list is a list representing the values in that row. What would the time complexity for finding an element be?

If I'm not mistaken, the average time complexity finding an element in a list using linear search is O(n), does that mean the average time complexity for a list of lists is O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

Comment: If `n` is the number of elements in the entire matrix, then it's just O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If n means the width and height of a square matrix, then a linear search in the matrix will take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. More generally, a linear search in a rectangular m×n matrix will take O(mn) time. Both are because that is the number of entries in the matrix, and a linear search will do O(1) work per entry.

If instead you use n to mean the total number of entries in the matrix, then the time complexity is O(n) for the same reason as above.

Note that the above assumes testing for the search target takes O(1) time (e.g. comparing primitive integers). If that's false, then you should multiply the above by the time complexity of the equality test; for example, if for some reason you have an m×n matrix of strings of length c, then the running time will be O(mnc).

Answer (score -2):

Well, you would have two indexes. So the complexity is equal two a list, but multiplied by two. That beeing said, if you want to model a matrix, you might consider using an array of arrays (not to be confused with a jagged array), because in normal circumstances, a matrix has a fixed size  (a `List<T>` is a wrapper around a `T[]` to allow adding and removing items).